# Suggestion of tag removal

Tags: discussion, tags

The tags [`physics-capitalism-technology`](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics-capitalism-technology) and [`physics-capitalism-propaganda`](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics-capitalism-propaganda) are being used by (and seem to have been created for) [this question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11119/did-richard-feynman-us-physicist-outline-a-deeper-critique-of-us-capitalism-an) alone. I suggest that they are removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That question is now closed and has a net negative score, so it will automatically be deleted after a week or so. At that time, the tags will automatically be removed from the site if no new questions are added with these tags. So unless the tags need to be removed urgently we don't need to do anything and the situation will resolve itself. I don't see any reason to prefer handling it manually; the tags are useless, but I don't think they are *dangerous*. Of course, if the question were to remain on the site long-term (which in this case would probably require major edits) we would want to remove the tags manually.

That said, any user with the [Edit Privilege](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) can expedite the process of this by just removing those tags from the question. As you have that privilege, you are welcome to use it for tidying up when you notice issues like this. The only caveat is that it can be disruptive to do too many at the same time, clogging the homepage (especially if the edits are to closed questions that are not likely to be reopened). There is no need to get permission on meta either. Asking on meta is useful if the tag is questionable but more common (more than 2 or 3 posts), or if there is a disagreement where your edit gets rolled back (don't start edit wars). But at first pass, you can handle these issues as you see them with your best judgment.